# The best practice for retrieving level editor data from an ios device

Tags: ios, plist

My google-fu hasn't turned up a direct answer to this, mainly because I think it's more theoretical than "why won't this work."

I'm learning Cocos2d and xcode. I'm making a simple game, and everything is going along smoothly. The game will have multiple levels, and the data for each level is stored in a plist.  However, I now want to create more levels.

Graphically building a level in a graphics program and then transcribing all of that data into a plist seems painful. However, I have a nice little touch screen ios device, where I should be able to turn my game into a quick-and-dirty level editor, and then store out that data into the exact plist format that I would need to load into the game.

I know that data created on an ios device winds up getting locked in into the untouchable file structures of the device itself. So, my question is this: **What is the best method for reclaiming any plist data out of my device that I create on the device?**

The few ways I can see getting access to the data would be to set up file sharing via iTunes, or sending data through email to myself. Both of which seem like overkill (I'm learning things, so maybe it's not that difficult as it seems based on googling up those ways). And again, I'm not trying to build a full-featured, end-user level editor that would require something like that. I just want an easy way on my end for me to get that data.

Any other (more) clever ideas?

Comment: I don't have any answers, but just a comment: You may get more answers by being more direct with your question. Delete the first paragraph, and move paragraphs 2 and 3 to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are in the Documents folder or somewhere else convenient:

Open Xcode's "organizer" window, click on the Devices tab and find your device. Click on the "Applications" section for the device, and select your application.

You can now download any files your app has created from the device to yor Mac.